# JavaScript - How to reset a local variable during recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, closures, global

There is an object with "value" or/and "children" as properties. The problem is to add all the values and return the sum. This is working. I have used recursion. I am using a global variable to store the sum.

Please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/ws6ty78b/1/

```
function sumup(node) {
  sum+=node.value;
  if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
    for (var i =0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        sumup(node.children[i]);
    }
}
return sum
}
```

The problem - While invoking the same function again, I am not getting same result. The sum is doubling. I DO KNOW why it is happening, that is since I am using a global variable.

Question - For the above problem, is there a way I get the same result for any number of invocations.

Please note the restrictions -

1) Do not change the function signature and declaration.

2) Use the 'sum' variable inside the 'sumup' function.

3) Do not use any extra variable.

4) Only make changes within the sumup function.

Comment: `Please note the restrictions` Very artificial, that's a bit silly...

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Not sillier than sitting clueless in front of the interviewer!

Comment: *"Do not change the function signature, both definition and declaration"*, and then *"Only make changes within the sumup function"*... what changes? You're not allowing any change.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for pointing out! Make changes in the definition ofcourse! not the signature and declaration

Comment: 'function sumup(xyz)' and 'sumup(abc)' will remain intact. Basically no currying or adding extra parameter. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `call` sumup while recursing and assign/test against a custom `this`:

```js
var obj = {
  "value": 4,
  "children": [{
      "value": 2,
      "children": [{
        "value": 1
      }]
    },
    {
      "value": 9
    }
  ]
};
var sum = 0;

function sumup(node) {
  //Only make change within this function body
  if (!this || !this.recurse) sum = 0;
  sum += node.value;
  if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      sumup.call({ recurse: true }, node.children[i]);
    }
  }
  return sum
}

console.log(sumup(obj));
console.log(sumup(obj));
```

Alternatively, you could do away with the global variable entirely and use a recursive `reduce` over the children instead:

```js
var obj = {
  "value": 4,
  "children": [{
      "value": 2,
      "children": [{
        "value": 1
      }]
    },
    {
      "value": 9
    }
  ]
};

const sumup = (node) => (
  node.value + (node.children
    ? node.children.reduce((a, child) => a + sumup(child), 0)
    : 0
  )
);

console.log(sumup(obj));
console.log(sumup(obj));
```

Comment: I thought all recursive problems have a base case condition.  Should we consider for loop iteration as base case here??

Answer (score 2):

You could simply sum the values of each child to the value of the current node:

```
function sumup(node) {
      sum=node.value;
      if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
        for (var i =0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
          sum+=sumup(node.children[i]);
        }
      }
      return sum
    }
```

Comment: @Lucalachini - One thing I am not able to visualize, in your code, wouldn't sum variable be reinitialised during recursion? (I know its working fine!)

Comment: @Bijoyvalappil it works because the js interpreter captures the value of the sum variable during the evaluation of the expression. If you try `sum=sumup(node.children[i]) + sum;` the solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Lucalachini - Oh! Firstly I was asking about how come the 2nd line 'sum=node.value' is not getting reset during recursion. The line sum=sumup(node.children[i]) + sum; works, I wonder why it would not work!

Comment: @Bijoyvalappil the sum is getting reset every time, but the sum expression keeps the old value of the sum variable. In effect, if you replace the line as I have shown, you will get an wrong result, because the function sumup is executed before the interpreter evaluates the sum variable. I tested on your JSFiddle and I got 18 instead of 16.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish your goal the function `sumup()` will be invoked N times. We don't know how much this N is, since it depends on the number of recursions for the children nodes. Also, thanks to the restrictions, we can't edit the function signature and cannot write code elsewhere to do pretty anything, not even manually set sum to 0.

**Therefore we need a way to distinguish one bunch of invocations from the NEXT bunch, and reset it.**

My idea is we set a threshold, use a [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp). From the first invocation, in the example, you have 5 seconds of time to keep calling and afterwards it will start anew. This is really all we can do unless another way to distinguish the invocations is provided.

EDIT: What I was trying here is keep all the recursions as a base case and not altering the object. Since OP has accepted that solution, I am adding a node resetter property. If any node has resetter not defined or null or zero or undefined, this will reset the sum. We must assume it is not defined in the started object. As I said this is kind of a weak assumption. By defining it when recursing, current sum is carried over.
I will also keep the original time threshold idea for eventual interest.

```js
var obj = {
  "value": 4,
  "children": [
    {
      "value": 2,
      "children": [
        {
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": 9
    }
  ]
}


const sumup = (function(){
  var lastTime = 0;
  var newTime = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  const timeThreshold = 5000; // 5 seconds
  return function(node) {
    newTime = new Date().getTime();
    if(!node["resetter"] || (newTime-lastTime >= timeThreshold)){
      sum=0;
      lastTime = newTime;
      }
      sum+=node.value;
      if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
        for (var i =0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
          sumup(Object.assign({"resetter":true},node.children[i]));
        }
      }
      return sum;
   }
})();

console.log(sumup(obj)); //16
console.log(sumup(obj)); //32! should print 16 everytime
```

Comment: That won't work - `console.log(sumup(obj));` is called in serial, there's no downtime, and changing anything outside the function to make it such that they're not called right after the other isn't permitted.

Comment: After your clarification I added an alternate solution using Object.assign.